# which one can be effective reference table or pointer table

Tags: c++

I have a tree in the form of several objects that make doubly linked lists. For direct access, in real time, these objects I thought about creating a reference table as size_tableau = nbr_object.
would you ideas about the declaration of the table?
if you have other suggestions I am taking.

---

{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

{0,3,6,7,10} {1,2,4,5,8,9}

{3,10} {6,7,10} {1,5,8,9} {2,4}

{3,10} {6} {7,10} {1,8} {5,9} {2,4}

Comment: What do you mean by `size_tableau = nbr_object`?

Comment: @Mene size of the table (which is an array) equals the number of objects.

Comment: Hm, still not clear what you want i'm afraid. But some advice: If you already have a search-tree, what I guess your lists example should be, you might be better of just searching in that tree. Otherwise I'm afraid you need to explain your problem/question in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

In c++ you can declare an array like so:

```
int numbers[11] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
```

The size is specified in the square brackets.

If you had a function that gave you the size, then you would need a dynamically sized array. `std::vector` is commonly used for this purpose.

```
void createTable(int table[11])
{
  std::vector<int> numbers (table, table + 11 * sizeof(int));
}
```

Comment: Hm... `void createTable(int[] table);` Is it a valid C++ code?

Comment: My bad, that was a typo. I have fixed it.

Comment: Hm... But `sizeof(table) == sizeof(int*)` now. And I'm sure this is not intended.

Comment: Alas, I had not tested my the code in my answer. If you want to be able to dynamically determine the size of an array passed in, you will have to pass in arrays that terminate in a null character then iterate through the array until you find the null character.

Comment: it is not what I wanted! I want to make a table reference or pointer to be able to enter my object in real time.
how I will declare this table?